# Cordova App network blocked

Tags: android, cordova

Having a strange situation. API call using chrome browser is working OK, but when doing same in Cordova based App, App is behaving as it has no connectivity. Cannot reproduce issue on all phones (Happening mainly on some Androids). Cordova version 3.7.2 is used. App was working ok until some 10 days ago.
Any idea what might be blocking API calls from App?

Comment: Can you paste your logcat?

Comment: I don't have access to it, as I cannot reproduce it, it is happening on some clients phone

Answer (score 0):

If used to work, try checking your API server for an SSL certificate expiration (including certificate chain and certificate authority since browsers on Android also look at the CA.)